# Extract a part of string on a particular reference

Tags: r

I need to extract number that comes after "&r=" in the below link.

```
http://asdf.com/product/eyewear/eyeglasses?Brand[]=Allen%20Solly&r=472020&ck-source=google-adwords&ck-campaign=eyeglasses-cat-brand-broad&ck-adgroup=eyeglasses-dersdc-cat-brand-broad&keyword={keyword}&matchtype={matchtype}&network={network}&creative={creative}&adposition={adposition}
```

Here's what i tried
C has my link stored in.

```
sub(".*&r=", "",c)

"472020&ck-source=google-adwords&ck-campaign=eyeglasses-cat-brand-broad&ck-adgroup=eyeglasses-dersdc-cat-brand-broad&keyword={keyword}&matchtype={matchtype}&network={network}&creative={creative}&adposition={adposition}"
```

This only gives me whole after part of the string .

I only need the number i.e `472020` .

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get it using `sub`

```
sub(".*=(\\d+)&.*", "\\1", z)
#[1] "472020"
```

or

```
as.integer(sub(".*=(\\d+)&.*", "\\1", z))
#[1] 472020
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(z, "(?<=\\&r\\=)\\d+"))
#[1] 472020
```

If there are several matches use `str_extract_all` in place of `str_extract`

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, here it is with the base R `regmatches`/`regexpr` combo:

```
 regmatches(z, regexpr("(?<=\\&r\\=)\\d+",z,perl=TRUE))
```

It uses the same Perl-flavoured regex as @akrun's stringr version. `regexpr` (or `gregexpr` if several matches of the same pattern are expected in the same string) matches the pattern, while `regmatches` extracts it (it is vectorized so several strings can be matched/extracted at once).

```
> as.integer(regmatches(z,regexpr("(?<=\\&r\\=)\\d+",z,perl=TRUE)))
#[1] 472020
```